# "Unhandled exception: Java.lang.exception" in code

Tags: java, android

I am making a translator app in Android Studio using Microsoft Translator API. However, when I am trying to store some translated text from Microsoft Translator API in a variable, I get the error "Unhandled exception: Java.lang.exception".

What does this error mean, and how can I fix it?

My code is:

```
public class Text extends AppCompatActivity {
    Context context;
    Button button;
    public static String text;
    TextView textOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Result);
    EditText textInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TextBar);
    public static String allTheTranslatedText;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.text_wall);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.LanguagePicker);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ConfirmationButton);
        context = this;

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.language, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);


                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                                        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.LanguagePicker);
                                        text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                                        String r = textInput.getText().toString();
                                        allTheTranslatedText = getTranslatedText(r); // this is the location of error.
                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });

    }
    public String getTranslatedText (String text1) throws Exception{
        Translate.setClientId("nnn333");
        Translate.setClientSecret("shoppingfor1gbatmymicrosoftdatamarket");
        String translatedText = "";
        switch (text) {
            case "English":
                translatedText = Translate.execute(text1, Language.ENGLISH); 
            case "French":
                translatedText = Translate.execute(text1, Language.FRENCH); 
            case "Spanish":
                translatedText = Translate.execute(text1, Language.SPANISH); 
            case "German":
                translatedText = Translate.execute(text1, Language.GERMAN); 
            case "Italian":
                translatedText = Translate.execute(text1, Language.ITALIAN); 
            case "Russian":
                translatedText = Translate.execute(text1, Language.RUSSIAN); 
            case "Mandarin":
                translatedText = Translate.execute(text1, Language.CHINESE_TRADITIONAL); 
            case "Korean":
                translatedText = Translate.execute(text1, Language.KOREAN); 
            case "Japanese":
                translatedText = Translate.execute(text1, Language.JAPANESE); 
        }
        return translatedText;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you're asking about a compiler error, don't try to post an abbreviated version of the error message, but instead post the **entire** message without editing. The text it contains is very important and needs to be displayed fully with your question.

Comment: The entire error just says: "Unhandled exception: Java.lang.exception" and nothing else.

Comment: Is that message from the compiler, when you try to compile your code, or from the JVM, when you try to run your code?

Comment: No, when I'm editing my code, a small red line appears on the right side of the screen, and when I hover on it, it says "Unhandled exception: Java.lang.exception".

Comment: ................ **WHERE**?

Comment: The error is on the same line where I added a comment saying, "this is the location of error." (The code that causes the error is "allTheTranslatedText = getTranslatedText(r).)

Comment: Oh ... you mean some comment that is scrolled way over to the right so that we can't see it????

Comment: Why do you have the `getTranslatedText (...)` throw Exception? You should always be specific with exception handling in your code.

Comment: Throwing `Exception` is a really bad idea:see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/5381/java-pitfalls-exception-usage/18023/pitfall-throwing-throwable-exception-error-or-runtimeexception#t=201701220135163406566

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message is being shown to you by your IDE in order to warn you that the java compiler will generate the same error later if you try to compile.

The error means that your `onClick()` method is invoking another method which has been declared with `throws Exception`, and java mandates that when you do this you have to either have code which catches the exception, or in turn declare the calling function also with `throws Exception`.

And since `onClick()` is an override, you are probably not allowed to add `throws Exception` to it.

So, you can either add a `try { ... } catch( Exception e ) { ... }` in your `onClick()` method, or declare your `getTranslatedText()` method ***without*** `throws Exception`.

Answer (score -2):

try to put your code in a try/ catch
example

```
try{
yourcodegoeshere..
}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

then in your compiler we will see your error and we will tell you why it happens

Comment: ***Never*** do `catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }` and especially ***never*** suggest to a novice to do such a thing.

Comment: why not ?, for debugging purpose?

Comment: because that's how errors go undetected.  If you can do something meaningful with the exception, do it.  If you can't, rethrow it, or better yet, do not even catch it.

Comment: Not a java guy, but that would be useful if after printing the stacktrace the error would be rethrown